# RPC is node fully synced

Tags: monerod, synchronization, rpc

In my test environment, which is `ssh`,`bash` and `screen`, I'm launching a `monerod` followed by several other programs `wallet-rpc/cli` and more, which are all depending on `monerod`.

To prevent any confusion, I would like to wait for `monerod` to be fully synced, before launching the dependent programs.

Can I RPC the daemon, and get the `local blockheight` / `network blockheight`, so I can wait for the sync to complete?

**My solution** (`Updated to wait if daemon is not ready`)

```
get_info() {
    local JSON=$( curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:28081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_info"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' | grep "$1" | grep -o '[0-9]*' )
    [ "${JSON}" = "" ] \
    || {
        echo ${JSON}
        return 0
    } \
    && {
        return 1
    }
}

wait_for_sync() {
    local TARGET=0
    local HEIGHT=0
    local CNT=0
    until [[ ${TARGET} -ne 0 ]]
    do
        ((CNT++))
        echo -en "${WHITE}Waiting for daemon: ${RED}${CNT}${RESTORE}\r"
        sleep 1
        TARGET=$(get_info '"target_height"' | grep -o '[0-9]*')
    done
    echo -ne "\033[2K"
    echo -n "${WHITE}Waiting for daemon to sync: ${HEIGHT}/${TARGET}${RESTORE}"
    while [ ${HEIGHT} -lt ${TARGET} ]
    do
        HEIGHT=$(get_info '"height"' | grep -o '[0-9]*')
        echo -ne "\r${WHITE}Waiting for daemon to sync: ${HEIGHT}/${TARGET}${RESTORE}"
        sleep 1
    done
    echo " ${GREEN}OK Synced${RESTORE}"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the best way to deal with this is just to start them all up at once. Monero RPC methods that are dependent on a fully synchronized blockchain will return with a relevant status code if the chain is not fully synced, and thus code can deal with this scenario as and when this happens.

If you find a situation it's imperative the blockchain is fully synchronized *before* starting some other tool/service, you could call the daemon RPC method [get_info](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_info) which shows you the daemon's current height in the `height` field and the blockchain target height in the `target_height` field. Therefore, you are syncing whilst `height` is less than `target_height`.

Comment: I was thinking about the `get_info` but. Right now it says `"height": 1306035,` and `"target_height": 1306014,` so that not really useful. Yes, I'm on `testnet`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure height greater than target height just means you have mined blocks that aren't confirmed on the blockchain yet. Therefore height greater than target height means you have fully synced.

Comment: For the record, I also popped blocks to test and verify my answer above w.r.t. get_info.

Comment: So, I did the `--pop-blocks` thing, followed by the `curl get_info` and fed the result into `| grep '"height"' | grep -o '[0-9]*'` and `| grep '"target_height"' | grep -o '[0-9]*'`. You are right, that while syncing `height < target_height`. When the sync catches up `height = target_height` all is good. If I continue to poll `target_height` it doesn't increase with `height` increasing. And I'm not mining.